# Vue.js, how to scroll to an anchor via ID without navigating to a route

Tags: javascript, vue.js, scroll, vue-router, anchor

I have Vue + vue-router for navigation through pages in an app, but I also need to the ability to move to an ID/Anchor without routing. Currently, router always activates and changes the URL to a new page with the name of the ID instead of moving to the ID on the same page.

```
<a href="#example">link</a>
```

The route set-up:

```
const router = createRouter({
  history: createWebHashHistory(),
  routes,
  scrollBehavior (to) {
    if (to.hash) {
      return {
        selector: to.hash
      }
    }
  }
})
```

When clicking the link, the page scrolls to the ID, *but* then routes away to a non-existent page  `http://localhost:8080/#/example`.

I'm really not sure how to use the anchor/ID without it being hijacked by vue-router.

Comment: I would try the `beforeEach` navigation guard, check against your collection of routes that  the route it's trying to navigate to isn't a valid one, and if not call `next(false)` inside the guard.

Comment: @dexygen I found navigation guard in the [vue-router docs](https://next.router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/navigation-guards.html), and it half works! It does prevent the routing to a blank page, however it still changes the url despite the docs saying it would stop it:

"And can optionally return any of the following values:
- false: cancel the current navigation. If the browser URL was changed (either manually by the user or via back button), it will be reset to that of the from route."

My beforeEach:
`router.beforeEach((to,from) => { if (!to.matched.length) return false }})`

Comment: Worst comes to worse you could then use history/push-state to revert the URL, but you'd think there was a better way

Comment: My other idea would be to find an alternative to using createWebHashHistory(), since anchors themselves put hashes in the URL

Answer (score -1):

if you are on the same page you can create a method and use [`window.scrollTo`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/scrollTo).

here it's an example function:

```js
scrollToContent() {
      window.scrollTo(
        0,
        document.getElementById("content").getBoundingClientRect().y +
          window.scrollY -
          120
      );
    },
```

Comment: This doesn't prevent the routing, the scroll itself works currently it just routes anyway.